# Why the compiler asks me to use the arguments directly?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a Pendulum in rust, while using my own vector structure. When I try to create a new Pendulum that uses the vector I created the compiler asks me to use the arguments directly. It works when I use position: vector::Vector::new(0.0, 0.0), but for me it should work when I try to use specifying the variable name and value.

I don't understand why I can't specify the arguments value.

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

struct Pendulum {
    origin: vector::Vector,
    position: vector::Vector,

    angle: f32,

    angular_velocity: f32,
    angular_acceleration: f32,

    r: f32, // length of the pendulum
    m: f32, // mass
    g: f32, // gravity
}

impl Pendulum {
    fn new(x: f32, y: f32, r: f32) -> Pendulum {
        Pendulum {
            origin: vector::Vector::new( x, y ),
            position: vector::Vector::new(x: 0.0, y: 0.0),
            angle: 1.0,
            angular_velocity: 0.0,
            angular_acceleration: 0.0,
            r: r,
            m: 1.0,
            g: 1.5,
        }
    }

    fn update() {}

    fn draw() {}
}

mod vector {

    pub struct Vector {
        pub x: f32,
        pub y: f32,
    }

    impl Vector {
        pub fn new(x: f32, y: f32) -> Vector {
            Vector { x, y }
        }

        pub fn add(&mut self, other: Vector) -> &Vector {
            self.x += other.x;
            self.y += other.y;

            self
        }

        pub fn set(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32) {
            self.x = x;
            self.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler returns me:

```
error: invalid `struct` delimiters or `fn` call arguments
src/main.rs:24:23
>    |
24 |             position: vector::Vector::new(x: 0.0, y: 0.0),
>    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>    |
help: if `vector::Vector::new` is a struct, use braces as delimiters
>    |
24 |             position: vector::Vector::new { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 },
>    |                                           ~                ~
help: if `vector::Vector::new` is a function, use the arguments directly
>    |
24 -             position: vector::Vector::new(x: 0.0, y: 0.0),
24 +             position: vector::Vector::new(0.0, 0.0),
>    |

error: could not compile `rust-pendulum` due to previous error
```

Comment: `Vector::new` is a function call that happens to construct a value. `Pendulum { ... }` is a struct literal syntax that *must* construct a value. Rust distinguishes between the two syntactically, and function calls don't support named arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust does not support named arguments for function calls. So `Vector::new(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)` is simply invalid syntax. It must be `Vector::new(0.0, 0.0)`.